# How do I find out the version of Zookeeper I am running?

Tags: apache2, versions, hadoop

I have an Ubuntu-12.04 VM running on my laptop.I have installed zookeeper on it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install zookeeper
```

Now for traditional Ubuntu programs I check the version using `--version` command line option. For example

```
gcc --version
```

gives the version of gcc as 4.6.3 (for e.g)

Similarly how do I find out the version of zookeeper? First of all it doesn't have a binary called zookeeper. It does have a binary called `zooinspector` which does not respond to  `--version.

I am very new to zookeeper. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest starting your search from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parameter+Reference this page and the following one describes a few of the command line parameters

Answer (score 29):

First you need to have a running Zookeeper server-instance.

Open a terminal, and start the Zookeeper server:

```
/usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```

*Note: Zookeeper will not start unless it can write to it's datadir and logfile.*

Open another terminal, and replace zkserver1 with the hostname\ip eg. 127.0.0.1 :

```
echo ruok | nc zkserver1 2181
echo status | nc zkserver1 2181
```

First line should respond with **imok**
Second line should respond with **Zookeeper version** + more.

Comment: Is it OK to run this on prod server, while another instance of Zk is running?

Comment: @ivanbalashow You shouldn't need to start another instance, so go straight to `echo ...` should be fine. If Zookeeper is installed through apt, you can also run `apt-cache policy zookeeper` to see it's version.

Comment: Thanks , echo status | nc <zookeeper-server> 2181 worked for me.